# Ubuntu on windows 10 wsl2 - chown chmod doesn't work on copied files

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on windows 10 (2004) WSL 2 from windows store.

I want to switch from cygwin, so i copy cygwin ssh configuration from `/mnt/d` to `~`  with

```
cp -R /mnt/d/dev/cygwin64/root/home/myuser/.ssh/ .
```

my usual ssh connection doesn't work and it seems to come from file/folder permission of `~/.ssh`

a `ls` on this folder doesn't work

```
$ ls -al .ssh/
ls: cannot access '.ssh/id_rsa.pub': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '.ssh/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '.ssh/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '.ssh/known_hosts': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa.pub
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? known_hosts
```

i tried

```
sudo chown myuser:myuser .ssh
sudo chown myuser:myuser .ssh/*
```

`.ssh` is still the same with `????????`

here is a view of the home folder

```
$ ls -al
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 5 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 25 10:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  4096 Aug 24 21:14 ..
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser  974 Aug 25 11:12 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Aug 24 21:14 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5026 Aug 25 10:53 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 24 21:19 .docker
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 24 21:15 .landscape
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    0 Aug 26 17:00 .motd_shown
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  807 Aug 24 21:14 .profile
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 25 10:54 .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    0 Aug 24 21:16 .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser  792 Aug 25 10:53 .viminfo
```

I tried to add a `wsl.conf` file with automount without success

```
$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ssh configuration is per user so you actually would need to copy it to `/home/myuser`. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/ provides an excellent how-to. Summarized and tweaked to match Cygwin path:

As your WSL user:

Edit your /etc/wsl.conf to match the following:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off"
mountFsTab = false
crossDistro = true

[filesystem]
umask = 0022

[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true

[interop]
enabled = true
appendWindowsPath = true
```

The additional metadata options as well as filesystem option should help ensure permissions are properly assigned. You also need to reset your WSL distro session in order for the changes to be read and propagated. From CMD or Powershell, do `wsl --shutdown`. Enter your distro again, usually with `wsl.exe`

Delete previous file and folder `.ssh` (with bad permissions)

Then:

```
cp -r /mnt/c/dev/cygwin64/root/home/myuser/.ssh/ ~/.ssh
sudo chown myuser:myuser .ssh 
sudo chown myuser:myuser .ssh/*
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Actually the matter isn't about ssh configuration, but about the file permission in the .ssh folder. chown and chgrp doesn't work. The files in the .ssh folder are still with `???????` permissions :(

Comment: Added some more details. Let me know if this works correctly.

Comment: theses new entries in wsl.conf didn't solve the permission problem (even after chown+chmod)

Comment: the bad file can't be updated. I had to delete and copy them again *after* updating the `wsl.conf` with theses options and reboot computer

Comment: A reboot shouldn't be necessary. But I did forget to add you need to restart your WSL session for changes in /etc/wsl.conf to apply. I will add this.

Comment: Ok I accepted your proposed edits and added the note about resetting wsl session. Can you upvote?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use the Ubuntu file system.

You can access it through the path `\\wsl$` on Windows.

Using the Ubuntu file system might create other issues. But file permissions wont be one because you would solely use the Ubuntu file system and sync these files to Windows (not the other way around).

Comment: I see where you're going with this but you should provide more information here for sake of clarity. Problem with this solution is if the 9P server goes down, which does happen in WSL2 (not as common in WSL1 to happen though still does from time to time.)

Answer (score 2):

To share your SSH Keys across both OS.

```
sudo umount /mnt/c

sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

Or Try

```
 ln -s /mnt/c/Users/MyUsername/.ssh ~/.ssh
```

The catch is to mount your ssh key in your windows 10 in such a way that wsl can read it.

Comment: This is good solution (I had used this myself before) but if interop breaks then you'll lose access to your ssh keys. Had this happen a painful way. Better to make a copy so that interop isn't required.